# shared memory allocation and forking child processes

Tags: process, shared

I got some doubt about how to allocate shared memory
using some shmget function.what's the syntax exactly ?
also i want to know how to fork child processes in pair which perform different functions individually and then output of processes is given by parent process.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah i under stood your question. Here is the syntax for allocating shared memory for different functions.

```
thread_identifier = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, num * sizeof(int), 0777|IPC_CREAT)
```

And for forking.

```
if (fork()==0) { printf("desired output "); for(i = 0; i < num; i++) { x[i] = 1 + (rand() % max); printf("%d \n", x[i]); *output *= x[i]; } printf("output %d", *output);
```

You can use `then else` loop for entering in another child process.